# Recursive query in SQLJ

Tags: java, sql, oracle, sqlj

I would like some help in **SQLJ** (yes...). I'm googling how to reproduce a recursive SQL query in this inline-java SQL. References are also welcome, because it has being really  hard to find also...

My SQL query:

```
WITH attachedemails(id, subject, filename) 
     AS ( 
        -- Ancora (224)   
        SELECT email 
        FROM   (SELECT addressee.email AS email 
                FROM   addressee 
                WHERE  addressee.email->from 
                    IN (SELECT address 
                        FROM   use 
                        WHERE use.user->nickname = User.nickname <arg>) 
                UNION 
                SELECT addressee.email 
                FROM   addressee 
                WHERE  addressee.to 
                    IN (SELECT address 
                    FROM   use 
                    WHERE use.user->nickname = = User.nickname <arg>))) 
               AS t 
        WHERE  email->DATE >= FROM <arg> AND  email->DATE <= TO <arg> )           

         UNION ALL 

         SELECT m.id 
         FROM   email AS m, 
                attachedemails AS c 
         WHERE  m.contained_in = c.id 
                AND m.DATE >= FROM <arg> AND  email->DATE <= TO <arg> ))
```

Basically, I'm getting all emails from some given user and email attached in other emails. I marked with  my Java arguments, which I should use to filter the results.

I'm aware that in order to return multiple rows using SQLJ we need a iterator, and that I can different levels of them in subqueries, but recursion is being extremely hard to simulate. Maybe there is some other kind of construction specifically for SQLJ that I'm not aware. I hope someone can help!

Comment: [SQLJ looks pretty dead?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQLJ) But if it just passes the query to the database, it could use whatever feature the underlying database has.

Comment: Yes, I know... not our choice, grad project. I will try if the whole query